# Required data not displayed in html.dropdownlist MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I am trying to populate some data from model to view in a dropdown list. For that I have created my model as

**Model:**

```
public class NoOfSupportingLanguages
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }
}
public class OrganisationModel
{
      public SelectList NoofSupportingLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

And on the controller side , something like this:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<NoOfSupportingLanguages> LanguageOption = new         List<NoOfSupportingLanguages>{
                new NoOfSupportingLanguages{ LanguageId = 1, LanguageName="English" },
                new NoOfSupportingLanguages{ LanguageId = 2, LanguageName="Arabic" },
                new NoOfSupportingLanguages{ LanguageId = 3, LanguageName="French" }
            };
            SelectList languageList = new SelectList(LanguageOption, "LanguageId");
            model.NoofSupportingLanguages = languageList;
            return View(model);
        }
```

**View:**

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NoofSupportingLanguages, "Number of languages to support :")
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlNoOfSupportingLanguages", Model.NoofSupportingLanguages)
```

but in my dropdown I am getting values as :

```
Web.Models.Organisation.NoOfSupportingLanguages
Web.Models.Organisation.NoOfSupportingLanguages
Web.Models.Organisation.NoOfSupportingLanguages
```

Please suggest some help .

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.NoOfSupportingLanguages , Model.ModelName, "Select Language") , replace this in your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in a clean MVC way you should change your model:

```
public class OrganisationModel
{
      public int SelectedLanguageId { get; set; }
      public List<SelectListItem> NoofSupportingLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> LanguageOption = new List<SelectListItem>{
            new SelectListItem { Value = 1.ToString(), Text = "English" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = 2.ToString(), Text = "Arabic" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = 3.ToString(), Text = "French" }
        };
        //here you can set selected value
        model.SelectedLanguageId = 1;
        model.NoofSupportingLanguages = LanguageOption;
        return View(model);
    }
```

And then you will be able to do like this:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NoofSupportingLanguages, "Number of languages to support :")
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguageId, Model.NoofSupportingLanguages, "Select Language")
```

Now when you **POST** your model it will automatically bind Selected LanguageId to `SelectedLanguageId` model property.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors with your code. First, to generate a `SelectList` you need to provide 2 property names (for the `value` attribute and the display text), so it needs to be

```
SelectList languageList = new SelectList(LanguageOption, "LanguageId", "LanguageName");
```

Next, you need a property to bind to, so you model needs to contain another property, say

```
public int SelectedLanguage { get; set; }
```

and then in the view its

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguage, Model.NoofSupportingLanguages)
```

so that when you submit the form, the value of `SelectedLanguage` will be the value of the selected option.

Comment: Always wondering what's better to use `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for solving this problem?

Comment: @teovankot, `SelectList` has a tiny performance hit because it uses reflection to generate the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. But its a bit more concise, although some don't like the 'magic' strings. It really just comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @teovankot, And in any case, I would always make the property in the view model `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so you can generate it either way.